# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preReleaseBuild'

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create project to .apk file but got this error when I type - ./gradlew bundleRelease:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preReleaseBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-gesture-handler.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-gesture-handler: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

I know there are some questions like mine but none is exact the same. I'm sorry if there is already existing solution, but I didn't found.

Answer (score 0):

You may not link the library react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: I've got an error Failed to get dependency config. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: maybe you should look at the setting.gradle to find if something wrong duplicate the react native gesture or wrong declaration compared to the doc